# Unsure how this returns an Int of functions

Tags: scala

I'm reading this scala book and a bit unsure on what this syntax translates to:

```
def bf: Int => Int => Int = i => v => i + v
```

1. bf is the name of the function.
2. after then colon is the function return type which is:

Int => Int => Int

I presume that the equal sign is the start of the function body, but not sure because then it has i => v => i + v.

Can someone clarify where each return type is and how to you break it down in your head so I can do the same :)

Comment: The `=` is the end of the type, and the start of the value. Not necessarily a function body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

return type of the code can be read as `Int => (Int => Int)`.
It is a function that takes single parameter of Int and returns a function that takes another Int parameter and returns Int.

If you are still getting confused, this is the longer way to write the same.

```
val bf: Int => (Int => Int) = (a:Int) => ((b: Int) => a + b)
        |_________________|   |____________________________|
               type                  outer function
                                          |________________|
                                           inner func returned by the outer func
```

Long answer:

It is normally called `curried function` or `function currying`.

I assume You already noticed this though, This method originally trying to  get sum of 2 Int values which is written as below.

```
val foo = (a: Int,b: Int) => a + b
```

any functions which takes multiple parameters can be transformed to nested single parameter functions a.k.a "curried function".
You may write it by your self just like your question code but You can call `.curried` to the method/function to get it as well.

`val bf = foo.curried //bf is exactly the same thing as you wrote`

This is usually used when you can't define both of the parameters at the same time so when you gets first value, make a function that `(b: Int) => YOUR_FIRST_VALUE_ALREADY_DEFINED + b`. and call it when you get second value.

How the curried function is used...

```
bf(4)(5) //9
val bar = bf(6) // (Int) => Int
bar(7) // 13
```

Answer (score 0):

functional types are associate to the right. 
for e.g.
Int => Int => Int is equivalent to Int => (Int => Int)

more details you can register and go through below lecture.
https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/lecture/fOuQ9/lecture-2-2-currying